# how to set icon in jsp?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, liferay

hello i m new in jsp and i want to set icon instead of my anchor tag.  i am using liferay ide eclipse.i have create **image** folder in docroot.and i have put my image in image folder and image name is 2.jpeg. i am writing following code in my jsp page but i cant get image as a icon. kindly help me.

```
  <%@ include file="/html/polling/init.jsp" %>

  <portlet:renderURL var="editpollURL">
  <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/polling/edit.jsp"/>
  </portlet:renderURL>
  <br/><a href="<%= editpollURL %>"><img  alt="hello kapil"src="/image/2.jpeg"/></a>
```

pls tell me what i should do?

Comment: hello stuart  thanx for editing , please tell me where am i wrong

Comment: You will get a notification in your StackExchange(left side top).See notifications and click on edit review.

Comment: @Baadshah.. i mean where i am wrong in my code.. why i cant get image? tell me..

Comment: is that image correct path correct ?

Comment: @Baadshah..yes i have docroot folder and i created image folder in docroot..so i write path like this "/image/2.jpeg.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom portlet / plugin is typically deployed in its own webapplication context, e.g. my-portlet. You try to address your image from "/images/2.jpeg", but it should be `/my-portlet/images/2.jpeg` - in order to make this more generic you could replace "my-portlet" with `<%=request.getContextPath() %>`, resulting in

```
<img alt="hello kapil" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/image/2.jpeg"/>
```

Of course, if you don't look up the context path this way, your plugin most likely is not named "my-portlet" so you'll have to replace this with the actual name of your plugin to hardcode the path.

You can find this out by yourself if you just inspect the HTML output of your portlet: Identify what HTML your portlet renders and check if there's a resource (image), or where else you'd expect it.